# Find all names in a mongoDB containing a given substring

Tags: scala, reactivemongo

Hi there I am using scala and play2-reactivemongo version 0.16.2-play26.
I want to be able to do a search query on a json collection where all names will be returned that contain a given substring. I have come across using $text with indexes but I am not sure how to set this up in the version of reactivemongo I am using. Is $text supposed to be declared in my code?

Does any have an example that is written in Scala?

Many thanks

Comment: I recommend to first design your query in mongoshell, then code it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @cchantep :)

I managed to solve this problem with this code:

```
def searchItem(name: String): Future[List[Item]] =
  jsonCollectionFuture.flatMap(
    _.find(Json.obj("name" -> Json.obj("$regex" -> (".*" + name + ".*"))), None)
      .cursor[Item](ReadPreference.Primary)
      .collect[List](-1, Cursor.FailOnError[List[Item]]())
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want a BSONDocument, please use the below code snippet:

```
val query = BSONDocument("columnName" -> "tally")
collection.find(query,Option.empty[BSONDocument]).cursor[BSONDocument]().collect[List](-1,Cursor.FailOnError[List[BSONDocument]]())
```